# Is there any automation tool for Symfony 2 framework in PHP

Tags: automated-testing, php

Is there any automation tool for Symfony 2 framework in PHP? If so, please suggest me some sites that help me study the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, I would suggest investigating the Symfony2 docs, specifically this link as a starting point.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html